# SSL Failure over Mobile Network

Tags: mobile, ssl, amazon-ec2

We're trying to implement SSL through our node server hosted on ec2. The SSL Cert is from GoDaddy, and we're actually hosting the https site over port 8081 and fwding that to 443.

Everything works fine for wired and wifi devices, but as soon as any one of us uses our mobile data connection (non wifi) to try to hit the https:// endpoint, we get no response.

Any ideas on why? Or even some background on what the difference would be between the two connections?

Edit: The connection is fine for the non-ssl site.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably having issues with the SSL certificate chain on your mobile OS.  You can confirm this by tethering or otherwise using a computer to access your endpoint on mobile data.  You also can run your endpoint through the analyzer here: https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html

If this is true, more than likely you'll need to reorder your certs (Android is fairly finicky about that).  See [this SU answer](https://superuser.com/a/347614) for more details about that process.

Comment: So what you're saying is that the mobile data certificate chain needs more than the wifi certificate chain? To clarify, the same device works over wifi, but not the mobile network.

Comment: Ah, if it works with WiFi on the mobile device then the problem isn't on the device.  Sorry about jumping to conclusions there.

Answer (score 0):

Is the SSL site running in port 8081 or 443?

Mobile (3G, Edge, ..) networks have lot stricter firewall rules and often transparent proxies so if you're trying to access port 8081 with SSL it will not generally work. Even when port would be open in their firewalls, some transparent proxy might try to understand it and fail to process it.

Comment: Alright, next steps will be to try running it directly through 443.  It kinda sucks because running the server as root is ill advised (and you need to run as root to run on ports less than 1000) but at least we'll get more info and see if that is the issue.

Comment: We use nginx or haproxy to listen 443 and 80 and just redirect traffic to app port. You need to start those as root but they can be configured to switch to safe user (e.g. "nobody") after opening the port.